# Import txt file content from One-Drive

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to import file content from .txt file located on One-Drive to variable, but I can not conduct with any solutions I found...

I need to import file content, update it and save again in the file. The problem is, that I can not access the file

I have tried to import it as a File System Object, yet it does not work, as the file type and extension are not correct.

I also tried using SPWeb object(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms476063(v=office.14)), yet it does not work as the link is not located on Share Point.

Could you please give me some hint regarding what method could I use in order to get this done?

Comment: Have you considered using REST API? It has some documentations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online). I am not yet sure if this will work or not, have not tried in Onedrive but I had some implementations in SharePoint and it works.

Comment: Please see the following pages and consider updating your question. Otherwise, it is likely to be closed without answers. https://superuser.com/help/on-topic  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   You might want to post the code you are using to try to access the file and save it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

First assign a drive letter to your OneDrive. There are tons of information on the web how to do it [(here is one of them).](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-assign-a-drive-letter-to-microsoft-onedrive-in-windows-10/)

Now, you can use below code to pull txt files in a folder.

```
Sub ListTextFilesInFolder()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ' OneDrive folder path, replace drive letter O with your assigned OneDrive.
    FolderPath = "O:\YourFolderPath\"

    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    End If

    i = 1

    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.txt")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = FileName
        i = i + 1
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```